# validate xss and allow all language characters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to do validation on input values to avoid SQL Injection and Cross site scripting in js files using Regular Expressions.

I want to allow numbers and **all languages characters** with some characters. But I am unable to get a regular expression for this.

```html
var sampleText="j’ai les réponses";
var reg = /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9\\-\\s ]+$/;
 if (sampleText != "" && !reg.test(sampleText)) {
     alert("Invalid Text.");
     return false;
 }
```

j’ai les réponses is a valid french sentence but it is throwing invalid input.

can any one help me in this.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to me. Why not use parameterized queries and escape on output?

Comment: After seeing your update, I thought about it some more and found another problem.  Please see the `Edit:` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well here are a couple of ideas for you to play around with.

First, you do not need to escape the dash `-` and whitespace `\s` characters inside your character class.

Also, it's good practice to move the dash to the front (or end) of the character class so that the regex engine doesn't try to make a range out of it.  And if you are using `\s`, you also don't need the space , since it will include it.

```
var reg = /^[-a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9\s]+$/;
```

But what will probably help you get on the right track is to take a look at what it is you are telling the script to do. What you are effectively saying with your logic is to see if your `sampleText` does not match any of the characters in your character class.  But because it is matching all of the letters, you are getting a pass on the test you are trying to perform.

A better way to go about it would be to do something like the following:

```
var sampleText="Rocking around the Christmas tree";
var reg = /[^-a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9\s]/;

if (sampleText != "" && reg.test(sampleText)) {
    alert("Invalid Text.");
}
else {
    alert("All of the characters are valid!");
}
```

Where you negate the character class by adding a caret `^` to the beginning of your class and then try to make a positive match with your expression by removing the exclamation mark, like this: `reg.test(...`.

What this will do is look for any characters that are not a part of your allowed list of characters and then flag it as `Invalid Text` if it does come across a character that is not in your character class.

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uzoLrr3q/)

**EDIT:**

After looking again at your character class, I think that `À-ÿ` is not a valid range.  The ranges are taken from the ASCII table.  If you take a look here, you'll see that the characters you are looking for are not part of the table.

[asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)

So when you do a range in regex, it allows characters in a range that it can find.  For `A-Z`, it is looking for the ascii values of `65-90`.  But there is not a range for your particular characters, so you'd have to add them in manually, like this:

```
var reg = /[^-a-zA-Z0-9\sÀÿé’']/;
```

Here, I added in the `é` and also the variants of the apostrophes `’'`.

[Here is an updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uzoLrr3q/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. the above reg expression is working only for the given sample text j’ai les réponses if any other word like Commençons we are using it is not allowing. I want to allow all languages characters or atleast english and french languages. Please help

Comment: You'll need to add in each character that you want to allow.  So add in the special `c` character to your character class and it should match that word.  If you have other special characters, add those in too.